# how to delete a cloned prefab class in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used the code Destroy(), but when I check the program while it's still running, the the Object is still there. Am I missing something?

```
 class: mobile
 {
      GameObject mobileObject;
      SpriteRenderer mobileSR;
      int height;
      int width;
 }



 void Start()
 {

     mobile clone;

     clone = Instantiate(mobile);

     Destroy(clone); //object clone didn't delete :(
 }
```

Comment: `Destroy` only marks the object for deletion in the next possible moment

Comment: If there is really the need to destroy some object immediately, there is the method `DestroyImmediate`, however, usage should be avoided if possible.

Comment: depends when do you check? Object may stay "alive" until the end of the frame .. in the next frame it should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

You're destroying your class instance. If you wanna destroy GameObject too, make your `mobileObject` property public and use `Destroy(clone.mobileObject);`

Edit: Best way to delete your instance and destroy object is like this;

```
class: mobile
{
  GameObject mobileObject;
  SpriteRenderer mobileSR;
  int height;
  int width;

  public void destroy(){
  Destroy(mobileObject); //deletes GameObject
  Destroy(this); //deletes instance of class

  }
}
```

then;

```
void Start()
{

 mobile clone;

 clone = Instantiate(mobile);
 clone.destroy();
}
```